# New artifact version is not listed after publishing to Maven Central

Tags: maven-central

We recently published a new version of existing artifacts. The version shows up if I explicitly type the version number in the URL.

- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.microsoft.azure.functions/azure-functions-java-library-rabbitmq/2.0.0-preview
- https://search.maven.org/artifact/com.microsoft.azure.functions/azure-functions-java-library-rabbitmq/2.0.0-preview/jar

But they are not listed on the artifact page.

- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.microsoft.azure.functions/azure-functions-java-library-rabbitmq
- https://search.maven.org/artifact/com.microsoft.azure.functions/azure-functions-java-library-rabbitmq

Is this is an issue with naming of the version or change in some other properties (I made quite a few) in the POM file?

Answer (score 2):

It seems to take a few days before the new version gets listed. It would be good to know the reason for this delay. [mvnrepository.com](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.microsoft.azure.functions/azure-functions-java-library-rabbitmq) now shows `2.0.0-preview` version. I expect [search.maven.org](https://search.maven.org/artifact/com.microsoft.azure.functions/azure-functions-java-library-rabbitmq) to also show it in a couple of days.

Answer (score 2):

Publication takes around 30 minutes, while the search engine might take several hours to be updated.

Quoting from the [Central repository guide](https://central.sonatype.org/publish/publish-guide/#releasing-to-central):

> Upon release, your component will be published to Central: this typically occurs within 30 minutes, though updates to search can take up to four hours.

Comment: Thanks @j1elo. In my case, the artifact was already listed, but the just-uploaded version was missing in the version-list for that artifact. It took a few days for the version to show up. A few months later, I happened to push another version but this time, the interval between pushing and listing was much smaller.